# Cannot register a U2F key with javascript & python APIs

Tags: javascript, django, fido-u2f

I'm trying to implement U2F authentication devices in my django app. The primary issue now is, all of my front-end registration calls fail.

I'm using the `u2f-api.js` script and the `python-u2flib-server` python script to implement this.

I am following this pattern:

1) Generate a key/challenge with the u2flib

```
from u2flib_server import u2f
app_id = 'https://127.0.0.1'
reg = u2f.begin_registration(app_id)
print reg 
# {'registeredKeys': [], 
   'registerRequests': [{'challenge': u'pLzGmABMwBzQkco6INeFNuPsAG6KhgfVeYFeV0QBf1g', version': 'U2F_V2'}], 
   'appId': 'https://127.0.0.1'}
```

2) Register the key from browser

```
var reg_data = {'registeredKeys': [], 'registerRequests': [{'challenge': 'pLzGmABMwBzQkco6INeFNuPsAG6KhgfVeYFeV0QBf1g', 'version': 'U2F_V2'}], 'appId': 'https://127.0.0.1'}

u2f.register(reg_data['appId'], reg_data['registerRequests'], [], function(resp) { console.log(resp) });
```

This consistently returns a `{errorCode: 2}` response, which essentially means bad request. However, I'm unable to determine what part of this request is invalid.

I am using `runserver_plus --cert certname` to run my local webserver so the site is served via HTTPS. I've also tried using NGROK to access my site over HTTPS and attempted the same code. I consistently get the same response.

I would appreciate any help, pointers or guidance on my implementation as I've been struggling for a few days and the existing documentation around U2F libraries and implementations is pretty thin.

-- Update --

I've actually made slight progress here. I am able to receive the generate the key response. However, I am still unable to register this key with the python library.

I end up having something like this on the server side:

```
response = {'challenge': 'okGbjnbE2V9cT42X2wm-PA9pm7k3KpTETVEv2SqEUxE', 'registrationData': 'BRS5y7dFXs0O60o2cUFc-SZtKG3jibpFQGuwQDyTQkSWeQUNWn\\u2026bEwIhALYcM1NospvymAbv83lTlpLjaa2ICSFQv-5RYfzkPCc9', 'version': 'U2F_V2', 'clientData': 'eyJjaGFsbGVuZ2UiOiJva0dianBnRTJWOWNUNDJYMndtLVBBOX\\u2026R5cCI6Im5hdmlnYXRvci5pZC5maW5pc2hFbnJvbGxtZW50In0'}

register_request = {'registeredKeys': [], 'registerRequests': [{'challenge': 'okGbjpgE2V9cD32X2wm-PA9pm7k3KpKN5VEv2SqEUxE', 'version': 'U2F_V2'}], 'appId': 'https://127.0.0.1:8000'}

u2f.complete_registration(register_request, response)
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/u2flib_server/u2f.py", line 45, in complete_registration
    return U2fRegisterRequest.wrap(request).complete(response, valid_facets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/u2flib_server/model.py", line 419, in complete
    _validate_client_data(resp.clientData, req.challenge, Type.REGISTER,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/u2flib_server/model.py", line 339, in clientData
    return ClientData.wrap(self['clientData'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/u2flib_server/model.py", line 261, in wrap
    return data if isinstance(data, cls) else cls(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/u2flib_server/model.py", line 328, in __init__
    super(ClientData, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/u2flib_server/model.py", line 239, in __init__
    kwargs = json.loads(arg.decode('utf-8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I'm stuck again! I've tried creating a json dumps out of the values before passing them to `u2f.register` to no avail- I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, digging up random blog posts and a lot of trial and error, I've finally been able to complete this task with the above mentioned libraries. I will post here an example of how I have achieved this. First, ensure you are running your local webserver over https at `https://localhost:8000` (or whatever port- but `localhost` is needed).

1. First, generate a challenge from the python library

   ```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_devices = [..get user device JSON blobs if they exist, or just blank]
        register_request = u2f.begin_registration('https://127.0.0.1:8000', user_devices)
        # return value to front end 
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'register_request': register_request
        })
   ```
2. In the front end, signal browser to begin U2F registration. This will emit a signal to the key to ready itself. Post the result from the registration to your register completion endpoint

   ```
    registerRequest = {{ register_request | safe }} //json result of above 
    var regReq = {'challenge':registerRequest.challenge, 'version': registerRequest.version}
    window.u2f.register(this.appID, [regReq], [], function(keyAuthResponse) {
        $.ajax({url: '/path-to-registration/', 
                type: "POST",
                data: keyAuthResponse, 
                success: function(res){ console.log('sent verification' }
        })
    })
   ```
3. On your server side, accept and verify the key

   ```
    data = reg{'challenge': request.POST.get('challenge'),
               'clientData': request.POST.get('clientData'),
               'registrationData': request.POST.get('registrationData'),
                'version': request.POST.get('version'),
    })
    #You need hte original register request, either in session or elsewhere to fetch
    register_request = request.session.get('_u2f_registration_request')
    device_details, facets =  u2f.complete_registration(register_request, data)
   ```

The `complete_registration` will return no errors if the device registered.

I hope this serves to help someone in the future.